# Extend Laravel package with the right tool

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my App I installed this package https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle to make `http/curl` requests.

I then created an `ExternalController` to extend the functionality of Guzzle Package, like so:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException as ClientException;

class ExternalController extends Controller
{
    protected $endpoint = '';
    protected $method   = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->debug = env("APP_DEBUG", false);
    }

    /**
     * Crypts Server call
     */

    public function encodeCall($method = 'GET', $endpoint = "server_status")
    {
        $EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL         = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL');
        $EXTERNAL_IP               = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_IP');
        $EXTERNAL_PORT             = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_PORT');
        $EXTERNAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN');

        //Skip some parameters for security reasons

        $base64hash                = base64_encode($str2hash);

        $request_url = "${EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL}://${EXTERNAL_IP}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}/manage/${endpoint}?salt=${salt}&hash=${base64hash}";

        $requestContent = [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept'       => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ];

        try {

            $client   = new GuzzleHttpClient();
            $curl     = $client->request($method, $request_url, $requestContent);
            $response = json_decode($curl->getBody());

            return response()->json($response);

        } catch (RequestException $RequestException) {

            return response()->json(['message' => (string) $ClientException]);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns Server Status
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getServerStatus()
    {
        $method   = 'GET';
        $endpoint = "server_status";

        return $this->encodeCall($method, $endpoint);
    }

}
```

I'm in the situation where I need to call some methods from another controller, like so:

```
//AnotherController.php

$server = new ExternalController;
return $server->getServerStatus();
```

I usually do not call a Controller within another Controller but I don't know enough Laravel to understand what is the correct tool.

I'm new to Laravel so perhaps I need to create a `ServiceProvider` to do this? If so what is the correct way of going about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can most definitely call a controller from another controller.

However, that's not what a controller is meant to do. In your particular case, you created a HTTP client and most likely, you would be using this in multiple places.

Here's how I'd do it. First, I'd define an HttpClientContract in `App\Services\Http`

```
namespace App\Services\Http;

interface HttpClientContract
{
/**
    * Crypts Server call
    */
    public function encodeCall($method = 'GET', $endpoint = 'server_status');

    /**
    * Returns Server Status
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function getServerStatus();

}
```

.. and then I'd have an implementation as follows:

```
namespace App\Services\Http;

use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException as ClientException;

class HttpClient implements HttpClientContract
{
    protected $endpoint = '';
    protected $method   = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->debug = env('APP_DEBUG', false);
    }

    public function encodeCall($method = 'GET', $endpoint = 'server_status')
    {
        $EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL         = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL');
        $EXTERNAL_IP               = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_IP');
        $EXTERNAL_PORT             = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_PORT');
        $EXTERNAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN = config('myconfig.EXTERNAL_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN');

        //Skip some parameters for security reasons

        $base64hash                = base64_encode($str2hash);

        $request_url = "${EXTERNAL_PROTOCOL}://${EXTERNAL_IP}:${EXTERNAL_PORT}/manage/${endpoint}?salt=${salt}&hash=${base64hash}";

        $requestContent = [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept'       => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ];

        try {

            $client   = new GuzzleHttpClient();
            $curl     = $client->request($method, $request_url, $requestContent);
            $response = json_decode($curl->getBody());

            return response()->json($response);

        } catch (RequestException $RequestException) {

            return response()->json(['message' => (string) $ClientException]);

        }
    }

    public function getServerStatus()
    {
        $method   = 'GET';
        $endpoint = "server_status";

        return $this->encodeCall($method, $endpoint);
    }

}
```

Finally, we would need to register our new Http Client in our application's service container.
We will use a Service Provider to achieve this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\HttpClient;
use App\Services\HttpClientContract;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class HttpClientServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
    * Register bindings in the container.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(HttpClientContract::class, function ($app) {
            return new HttpClient();
        });
    }
}
```

We also need to add this new Service Provider into our container.
So, in `config/app.php` and in your `$providers` array, you would need to add the following:

```
'providers' => [
    //
    //

    App\Services\Http\HttpClientServiceProvider::class
]
```

Now whenever, you need to use it, you would just need to resolve it from the container. If you type-hint the dependency into your method, Laravel will automatically resolve it through the container by using Reflection.

```
public function makeRequest(HttpClientContract $client)
{
    return $client->encodeCall(); 
}
```

We are applying several OOP principles by doing it this way. 
First, we are "coding to an interface" instead of an implementation.

If your implementation of your HTTP client changes in the future, you would just need to simply bind the new one.

We are also injecting the dependency into our method instead of instantiating it inside the method. This allows us to swap/mock our HTTP Client's implementation during testing, which in the case of a HTTP Client, makes a lot of sense.

Read more about [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers) and [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container).

Comment: Thank you very much. This is great!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need a service. I can put shared code in the service and call it from different controllers / commands / jobs / etc.

**Service**

```
namespace App\Services;

class MyService
{
  public function getStatus()
  {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

**Controller A**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\MyService;

class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(MyService $myService)
  {
    $this->myService = $myService;
  }

  public function index()
  {
     $response = $this->myService->getStatus();
  }
}
```

**Controller B**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\MyService;

class MyOtherController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct(MyService $myService)
  {
    $this->myService = $myService;
  }

  public function index()
  {
     $response = $this->myService->getStatus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, services are good place to put common code - and controllers should use that services instead of call to each other

It is hard to put some example but I try to explain in your case what to do: Insteado of create ExternalController  create ExternalRequestsService which will prepare data and send requests using guzzle to external API, and in your controllers only use that service.

Comment: Ok I'll try it out and let you know!